# Lost Sessions on Drupal Commerce Checkout

Tags: 7, commerce, sessions, ssl

Recently we have been experiencing Page Not Found errors during the checkout
process of our Drupal Commerce site. The problem seems to occur when a customer
travels from the checkout page to the shipping page. We use the secure pages
module in mixed mode operation, but the checkout and shipping pages are served
over https as shown below:

- cart - http
- checkout/% - switch to https
- checkout/%/shipping - remain on https

I have been trying to debug this issue, but there are no errors in the logs.
Somehow the session is being lost between these two pages. Does anyone have any idea how to debug this issue?

We are using the Memcache API, Commerce UPS and Commerce USPS modules as well. So far this issue has occurred with IE 11, Chrome and Firefox browsers.

Thank you,

Paul